# JAVA - Converting from byte[] to hex representation

Tags: java, hex, arrays

Is there any way of converting from byte[] to hex representation?
I've search everywhere but i can't find anything! Can someone please help me?

Comment: And what do you call "hex representation" exactly?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Did you test those methods? Pretty sure `if (len < 0) {` should be `if (len > 0) {`. BTW, I think some of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/) are by far more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
private static String   digits = "0123456789abcdef";


   public static String toHex(byte[] data){
    StringBuffer    buf = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i != data.length; i++)
    {
        int v = data[i] & 0xff;

        buf.append(digits.charAt(v >> 4));
        buf.append(digits.charAt(v & 0xf));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```